# Forcibly return control during execution of a blocking method

Tags: c#, asynchronous, blocking

I'm executing an external method `SaveCurrentDocument()` via C# Interop that is blocking. That method pops up a dialog box asking users to "Save As". I need to automatically type something into this window and press OK. My problem is the method is blocking. So I cannot do the following:

```
SaveCurrentDocument(); // this is blocking
SendKeys(savePath);
SendKeys("{ENTER}");
```

How do I forcibly return control from a blocking method? My current plan was to start a `BackgroundWorker` and execute the method within its callback, thereby blocking the worker but not my main thread. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can break a blocking call from within the same thread in C#.
The problem is, BackgroundWorker's CancelAsync() doesn't actually stop the worker, or its current method, it sends a signal that the activity should be stopped, and if you're in an interop blocking call, you're not going to get through.

While not ideal, you could delegate the interop call to a separate thread from within the BackgroundWorker, while keeping the handle to it handy.
Unfortunately, I know next to nothing about SendKeys, so I can't help you there.

That said, as M. Francis pointed out, you're probably best off checking if you can get a C# solution to writing the file (if it's a standard format like xlsx, docx, pdf, xml, or a fairly large collection of others), and using standardized solutions to saving the file.

Answer (score 0):

I'd strongly recommend you don't use SendKeys for this. If I'm using another program at the time this is called or have another window active, the keys will send to whatever I'm doing and your method won't work. I'd suggest not using a SaveCurrentDocument that relies on a pop-up that needs user-typed input if you're going to have to use SendKeys. Try just using a StreamWriter or similar so you can avoid needing a pop-up at all. You can also set the FileName property if you're using a SaveFileDialog.